# MCP23017s and arduino problems

Tags: arduino, i2c, expander

I'm not native English speaker, so forgive me my bads.

Ok. Here's the deal.

In my Arduino UNO I need more outputs and inputs. I bought 3 MCP23017s. One of them for receive states from 8 microswitches and other to control 32 LEDs.
LED states depends on which microswitch is actually pushed(only one of them could be pushed in time). For example:
When I push button on B block(0x20 mcp23017s) in 0 pin, all I want to do is send 10101010 to 0x21s block A. And it's working for only one button.
When I connect second button I want to send 10101010 to 0x21s block B.
And there's problem.
It doesn't work. For one button everything is ok, but for more than one it's not.
No matter if I push first or second button it always send 10101010 to 0x21s A block. It send 10101010 to 0x21s B block only, when I push 2 buttons at the same time, but it send bytes to A block too...

Hardware is ok, because I checked it for one button and everything was working well, so problem must be hidden in software.

I know that you could don't get what I mean, so here is code:

http://pastebin.com/YiJUmqba

```
#include "Wire.h"

byte buttons = B00000000;

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x21);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x21);
  Wire.write(0x01);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();
// To set all of 0x21 pins as outputs

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.write(0xFF);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
  Wire.write(0x01);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();

// To set all of 0x20 pins as button inputs
}

void loop()
{
  buttons = B00000000;
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
  Wire.write(0x13);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x20, 1);
  buttons = Wire.read();

  switch(buttons)
  {
    case B00000001:
    // A block
      Wire.beginTransmission(0x21);
      Wire.write(0x12);
      Wire.write(B01010101);
      Wire.endTransmission();
      break;
    case B00000010:
    // B block
      Wire.beginTransmission(0x21);
      Wire.write(0x13);
      Wire.write(B01010101);
      Wire.endTransmission();
      break;
    default:
      // A block
      Wire.beginTransmission(0x21);
      Wire.write(0x12);
      Wire.write(B10101010);
      Wire.endTransmission();

      // B block
      Wire.beginTransmission(0x21);
      Wire.write(0x13);
      Wire.write(B10101010);
      Wire.endTransmission();
      break;
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

I need this in my project which is very important for me, so please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you confirm that what you read from the first MCP is actually what you expect? Or to ask the same question differently: Can you find out if your input or your output is wrong?

Comment: I think I can. I did this few days ago when I was learning how to use mcp23017. I was using code from tronixstuff.com:
http://tronixstuff.com/2011/08/26/tutorial-maximising-your-arduinos-io-ports/
But I was capturing data from one of mcps and send it to another mcp.(example 41.3 from this site). Everything was working.

Comment: Ok. I checked input and output and everything is ok. I managed to write something to A block then B block and it's working. I don't know what the hell is wrong with these buttons omg...
If I want to send the same data from buttons to A and B blocks then it's working. When I send different data to A block and B black it's not working as it should be...

Comment: Could you add what exactely your software is supposed to do - I still do not quite understand what you are trying to to. Maybe you can make an example (the text above is hard to understand for me - non native english speaker as well, maybe that's the reason).

Comment: For debugging purposes, you can try the following: Remove the whole switch case and replace it with two simple if questions: if (b00000001) -> switch on one LED; if (b00000010) -> switch on another one .. try to debug your input values first and check if they are really what you intend them to be. Last thing to check: Check all buttons (press one, read the value, .. proceed to next one) - maybe there are some dependencies. Once you confirm that you get exactely what you expect. Do the same for your outputs. Ignore any inputs, and write code for each output, then test it.

Comment: Ok. I will try. Let's suppose that I have 2 objects. First object is connected to all 8 pins in block A of expander(address: 0x21) and second object is connected to all 8 pins in block B of the same expander.
I have 2 buttons(I want 8, but so far I need to solve this problem) connected to expander at 0x20. I have 4 green and 4 red LEDs connected to each of blocks at 0x21 expander. Normally only green LEDs are turned on. I want to turn them off and turn on red LEDs when one of the buttons is pushed. If button 1 then LEDs are changing(green off and red on) at A block. If button 2 then at B block

Comment: I did this. I wrote 2 for functions to turn on different LEDs on different blocks(first A. After all done at A then B block) and it was working. Also I did something similar to this with button(first button pressed so green turned on, second button pressed so red LED turned on). Everything works fine. I tried with integer and byte type and there's no difference.
I tried to change switch function to if() functions, but it wasn't working too...

Comment: Make your life easier: Throw out all the case statements (except for the first), test. Does it work? Take only the second case statement: Does ist work?

Comment: One more thing. As far as I know it's quite easy to add a UART (communication) to your design -> you might want to do that.

Comment: I threw out first case statement and it was working as I want, but when I threw out second case statement then nothing happened. It's strange because they are exactly the same. Of course they are different only by A or B block

Comment: Ignore what I wrote before .. Try the following: Set b00000001, wait 2 seconds, set b00000010, wait 2 seconds, set b00000100, wait 2 seconds (and go on like this). You should see a single LED lighting up, then the next and so on .. can you do that?

Comment: Nah. I don't understand what happened. Maybe somebody destroy my button circuit, but I wrote program with if() functions, ONLY ifs, without else if construction and it's working, but with another button. Probably of them is damaged. Thank you for helping me. I think it will work good now.